# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'char' was corrupted

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        printf("Enter a Character: ");
        scanf("%s", &ch);

        if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9'))
            printf("The character is a numeral\n");
        else if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z'))
            printf("The character is in upper case\n");
        else if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z'))
            printf("The character is in lower case\n");
        else
            printf("The character is a special character\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to read a character input from user and display the character type. However everytime after running the last scan of the program, it will have a debug error. I am using Visual Studios C++ 2010 Express.

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ch' was corrupted.

Please help!

Comment: Using `%c` is for single characters.  If you write `%1s`, you will also read at most one character, but you'll also get a null byte added after that character, which is part of the trouble you ran into in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To scan a char use

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

Using wrong format specifier will lead to undefined behavior.

Please make sure you ignore the newline char and do it by placing a space before `%c`

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

The space before the `%c` will make sure that the newline char in the buffer gets ignored. i.e space gobbles the newline char.

Comment: have tried that, but doing that will make it worse. The next scanf will take in the 'enter' keyed in on the previous scanf.

Comment: @Jeffrey Please read the whole answer you need to ignore the newline char and for it place a space before `%c`

Comment: so sorry didnt see that carefully. thanks! it works!

Comment: yea i know, but it requires 5mins to do so.

Answer (score 1):

In scanf,

If you want to the single character you have to use the control string `%c`. `%s` for 
getting the string.

So change the scanf into

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```