# In Visual Studio 2013, "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'b' was corrupted."

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I would first like to thank you for looking into my question.

I have been coding using Code Blocks ever since I started coding with C, and recently I had to switch to using Visual Studio for my college lab assignments. We had a pretty easy assignment this week, but I seem to keep running into this error that ONLY pops up when using Visual Studio, and not in any other IDEs. I was wondering if someone could help me resolve this issue, and tell me what I am doing wrong? I will attach my code below.

Thank you so much!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
void main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a, n;
    char b ='y';
    while (b == 'y')
    {
        n = rand() % 3000 + 1;      // 1-3000


        puts("I have generated a number between 1 and 3000. Can you guess mynumber?\nPlease type your first guess (0-3000):");
        scanf("%d", &a);

        while (a != n)
        {
            if (a > n)
                printf("Too high. Please try again.\n");
            if (a < n)
                printf("Too low. Please try again.\n");
            scanf("%d", &a);
        }
        printf("Excellent! You guessed the number!\n");
        printf("Would you like to play again? (y or n)\n");
        scanf("%s", &b);
    }
    printf("Have a nice day.\n");
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

This code is designed to generate a random(ish) number from 1-3000, and have the user guess it. The user then has the option to choose to play again or not. The error occurs when the user types 'n' to end the outer while loop.

Thanks again!

Comment: Seriously... even if you were too lazy to search, surely these dozens of answers popped up when you typed your question title into the box. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Run-Time+Check+Failure+%232+-+Stack+around+the+variable%22+scanf

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'char' was corrupted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935712/run-time-check-failure-2-stack-around-the-variable-char-was-corrupted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heed the dangers of `scanf`:

```
scanf("%s", &b);
```

`b` is a `char`, yet you gave `scanf` the specifier of `%s`.  The `%s` specifier is for character buffers, not single chars.  What is happening is that `scanf` assumes that `b` is a pointer to a buffer, and thus you get a memory overwrite.

You should specify `%c` as this is the specifier for a single char.

Also, just because you didn't see this in Codeblocks (probably using `gcc`) doesn't mean the program was ok, and it is only Visual Studio has a problem.  The program was wrong, and what you observed is *undefined behavior*.  When you overwrite memory, anything can happen, including "working ok".